# Python - flask - flashed messages are skipped (not appearing) and webserver returns responses straight away

Tags: python, flask

I am very new to Python flask and webserver concept in general but have managed to create a simple webapp.

It basically consists of a home page with a form to fill in and a submit button which returns a flashed messages when : 1) all fields are filled correctly and 2) not all fields are filled.

My code looks like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = preference_form(request.form)

    print(form.errors)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        age = request.form['age']
        address = request.form['distance']
        date = request.form['date']

        if form.validate():
            flash('All good!')
        else:
            flash('Oops! All details are required to provide accurate results!')

    return render_template('home.html', form = form)

@app.route('/results', methods = ['POST'])
def return_results():
    name = request.form.get('name')
    age = request.form.get('age')
    address = request.form.get('address')
    result = function_a(name=name,
                  age=age,
                  address=address)
    return result
```

The flash messages worked as desired but after I added the `return_results()` route, after the form is filled (whether complete or incomplete) it brings me straight to `/results`.

Could you please tell me what am I missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should render your flash messages in your template file. Add following code snippet in your template which you want to show the flash messages or your layout template file:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class=flashes>
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

UPDATE: One view function with three execute path will meet your needs.

1)if the request method is get, just render the home.html without flash message;

2)if the request method is post and the form data pass the validation, render the 
result.html with success flash message;

3)if the request method is post but the form data doesn't pass the validation, render the home.html again with the failed flash message.

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"]
def index():
    form = PreferenceForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            flash("success.")
            result = func(age=form.age.data, 
                          date=form.date.data, 
                          name=form.name.data, 
                          address=form.address.data)
            return render_template("result.html", result=result)
        else:
            flash("failed!")       
    return render_template('home.html', form=form)
```

Comment: I have something similar in my template. As I mentioned in my question, before I added the `return_results()` function, the flash messages got returned as expected, but not after I added that function.

Comment: Your `return_results` view function didn't flash anything.

Comment: And you didn't render a template file in it.

Comment: are you suggesting put the lines where it validates the form and returns flash messages in `home()` in `return_results()` instead? And if this is the case, of course the rendering of a template file is required to be added to `return_results()` as well?

Comment: It's all depend on your design of your application. If we can finish the information collect in one view function(endpoint), Why do we need the second one(`/resutls`).

Comment: as i mentioned, my knowledge on this is limited and my rationale to have another endpoint is I imagine something like google search, after I submit my search query it would return a new page containing the results.

Comment: @user7799677 I have updated my answer. You can finish your function with only one view function.